# Is there any way to add rows of excel in java list using apache poi

Tags: excel, list, arraylist, apache-poi

Hi all I want to add rows of excel in java list using apache poi like

list.add(rowl);
list.add(row2);
.
.
.
.
list.add(rown)

any help would be appreciable,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mean `Row createRow(int rownum)`?
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html

Comment: i dont want to create row in excel i just want to add row of excel in list